# Recommendation for Purim divrei Torah (not "Purim torah")

Tags: product-recommendation, torah-study, purim, jewish-books

I've been reading through the [Malbim Esther](http://amzn.com/1568711352) and have found it fascinating reading, and I was wondering whether there are any other notable seforim with divrei Torah about Purim. I am going through the Pachad Yitzchok on Purim, and I was wondering whether there are any other notable recommended sforim. Thanks!

Comment: R' Zevin's holiday sefarim have some nice Purim Divrei Torah. Translated into english by artscroll as well.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few interesting ones - most pretty lengthy, but they can be mined for shorter nuggets too - in Yaaros Devash, by R. Yonasan Eibeschutz, and Derashos Chasam Sofer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Sefer called [Otzros HaTorah - Purim](http://www.zbermanbooks.com/Page.asp?ID=913866aaca735b055c48328a6c1074c7d146d2af85ba1e45c7fcf415dfe230e1&ProductID=134945&CategoryID=7407) that is a Likut of many interesting and notable Divrei Torah. It is available on Purim as well as all the other Yomim Tovim.

Answer (score 1):

The VBM has published a few new Divrei Torah on each holiday, including Purim, every year. The Divrei Torah are collected and available online in their [Holiday Journals](http://www.vbm-torah.org/holiday.htm) (the Purim section is [here](http://www.vbm-torah.org/purim.htm)).